# How can I override Cache-Control max-age property

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a have an HTML page which is served from the node server and I set a large value for max age --

```
function setCustomCacheControl(res, mimePath) {
  try {
    const cachedMimeType = ['text/html', 'text/css', 'text/javascript', 'application/javascript', 'text/plain', 'text/css', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/bmp', 'image/webp', 'image/svg+xml'];
    if (cachedMimeType.indexOf(serveStatic.mime.lookup(mimePath)) > -1) {
       res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400000'); 
    } else {
      res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
      res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      res.header('Expires', '-1');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Cache-Control: error', e);
  }

}
```

After setting this value if I am changing any JS or CSS then I am not getting an update on browser unless I am doing a hard refresh or clearing the cache. The reason is that I am also setting the max-age for HTML page so the browser is always loading the old content.

At this point, I removed the HTML, CSS, and JS from the cached array list and put a lower max-age property.

```
function setCustomCacheControl(res, mimePath) {
  try {
    const cachedMimeType = ['text/plain', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/bmp', 'image/webp', 'image/svg+xml'];
    if (cachedMimeType.indexOf(serveStatic.mime.lookup(mimePath)) > -1) {
       res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=24000'); 
    } else {
      res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
      res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      res.header('Expires', '-1');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Cache-Control: error', e);
  }

}
```

But, I am still not getting the updated page unless I am doing a hard refresh or clearing the cache as the browser is serving those file from cache.

**My Question is, is there any way I can override max-age property value or ignore max-age property for those HTML, CSS and JS file?**

Thanks
Ruzdi

Comment: Aren't you setting the `ETag` header or the `Last-Modified` header?

Comment: @Pubudu I checked ETag is getting set automatically. But the problem is that at the first step we cached HTML which was a big mistake and as it was cached for a month after the latest deployment all users are not getting the updated code. We need a way which can override max-age and user can get the latest update.